# Alinhar conteúdo da div

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte layout: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de alinhar as imagens uma ao lado da outra, mas com o texto sempre na parte superior.
Há alguma solução para esse problema sem ser uma resolução com `position: absolute` (pois atrapalharia na responsividade)?

Segue meu código:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

html,
body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.movies {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 1800px;
  max-width: 1440px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.movies__box {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.movies__box h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.movies__box p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.movies__box img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="movies">
    <div class="movies__box">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore nihil quas sit pariatur libero quidem corrupti doloremque commodi accusantium quisquam quibusdam enim, maxime, repudiandae exercitationem ex laudantium illo, quam vero.</p>
      <img src="https://underscoremusic.co.uk/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/no-poster.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="movies__box">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet.</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit magnam ducimus, dolores harum laboriosam iure incidunt quod necessitatibus sequi ex?</p>
      <img src="https://underscoremusic.co.uk/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/no-poster.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="movies__box">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore nihil quas sit pariatur libero quidem corrupti doloremque commodi accusantium quisquam quibusdam enim, maxime, repudiandae exercitationem ex laudantium illo, quam vero.</p>
      <img src="https://underscoremusic.co.uk/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/no-poster.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: O texto vai ter no máximo o tamanho do primeiro item?

Comment: Sim, exatamente!

Comment: já tentou usar bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução é usando `flex` no co "card" que seria a sua dis com classe `.movies__box` , então vc coloca `flex-direction: column` para os textos e imagem ficarem uma acima do outro e para finalizar um simples `margin-top: auto` na imagem vai fazer elas se alinharem no final do container, como na imagem abaixo. Só com 3 linhas de CSS já alinhou de forma automática, independente da quantidade de texto! ;)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código da imagem acima.** Exiba o código em tela cheia!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

html,
body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.movies {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 1800px;
  max-width: 1440px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.movies__box {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movies__box h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.movies__box p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.movies__box img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 80%;

  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="movies">
  <div class="movies__box">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore nihil quas sit pariatur libero quidem corrupti doloremque commodi accusantium quisquam quibusdam enim, maxime, repudiandae exercitationem ex laudantium illo, quam vero.</p>
    <img src="https://underscoremusic.co.uk/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/no-poster.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="movies__box">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit magnam ducimus, dolores harum laboriosam iure incidunt quod necessitatibus sequi ex?</p>
    <img src="https://underscoremusic.co.uk/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/no-poster.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="movies__box">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore nihil quas sit pariatur libero quidem corrupti doloremque commodi accusantium quisquam quibusdam enim, maxime, repudiandae exercitationem ex laudantium illo, quam vero.</p>
    <img src="https://underscoremusic.co.uk/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/no-poster.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando!

Comment: @ThalesMaia sem problemas Thales que bom que ajudou!